# Does journalctl give access to all logs?

Tags: logs, rsyslog, systemd-journald

In my university we studied about `rsyslog`, and how it stores logs and where it stores them (`/var/log/`), and how to configure it ...

Now, I learned (by surfing on the internet) that a new way of storing log files has seen the day with `systemd-journald`. To access the logs stored by this service you use the command `journalctl` which I really like the simplicity and the power of this last one. I know also that `rsyslog` is kept in the latest versions of major Linux distributions, because a lot of packages depends on it.

My question is : by using `journalctl` to access the log data, am I getting access to all the log data that exists on my system ? or is there a situation where some log data are only accessible using the old way (`less /var/log/some_log_file`).

To put my question in another way for those who didn't understand it : by using `journalctl`, could I completely forget about using `less /var/log/some_log_file`.

Comment: ``journalctl`` only acess ``systemd-journald`` logs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/864722/where-is-journalctl-data-stored so you still need to read logs created through syslog and other logs created by apps (like access log for webservers etc).

Comment: systemd/journal does not replace rsyslog - there is a significant overlap though.

Answer (score 1):

- You can't be sure that you actually are receiving all logs without inspecting all the code on your system. Any program is free to log using any mechanism - saving to file, keeping logs in memory for saving when triggered by a signal, or anything else you can think of. In some cases the difference between a "log" and machine-readable content meant for further processing can be a matter of perspective, so there's no solution which fits every program.
- For a simple service, `journalctl -u service_name` will show the standard output and standard error of that service. Other logging methods like `logger` can be configured to direct content to the systemd logs.
- Any program which is still logging to files in /var/log *probably* isn't logging in such a way that the logs are available in `journalctl` (what would be the point of the redundancy?), but it *could*.

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html: Usual messages via `syslog` call will be visible in the local `journalctl`. Messages received from other nodes (syslog deamon listening on port 514) will -- by default -- _not_ be shown.